# ERRO DO COMPILADOR INTERNO Visual Studio 2017 com SFML

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Estou tendo um problema para compilar um codigo no visual studio 2017 com as bibliotecas do SFML, quando eu tento compilar ele da o seguinte erro:

> ERRO DO COMPILADOR INTERNO em 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe'
>       Escolha o comando de Suporte Técnico no menu de Ajuda do Visual C++,
>       ou abra o arquivo de ajuda do Suporte Técnico para mais informações
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(358,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" foi encerrado com o código 2.

Alguem sabe o que eu posso fazer pra arrumar?

Edit: Eis o código que esta gerando erro:

```
include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Bouncing Mushroom");

    //Criando Textura
    sf::Texture mushroomTexture;
    mushroomTexture.loadFromFile("mushroom.png");
    sf::Sprite mushroom(mushroomTexture);
    sf::Vector2u size = mushroomTexture.getSize;
    mushroom.setOrigin(size.x / 2, size.y / 2);
    sf::Vector2f increment(0.4f, 0.4f);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if ((mushroom.getPosition().x + (size.x / 2) > window.getSize().x && increment.x > 0) || (mushroom.getPosition().x - (size.x / 2) < 0 && increment.x < 0))
        {
            // Reverse the direction on X axis.
            increment.x = -increment.x;
        }

        if ((mushroom.getPosition().y + (size.y / 2) > window.getSize().y && increment.y > 0) || (mushroom.getPosition().y - (size.y / 2) < 0 && increment.y < 0))
        {
            // Reverse the direction on Y axis.
            increment.y = -increment.y;
        }

        mushroom.setPosition(mushroom.getPosition() + increment);
        window.clear(sf::Color(16, 16, 16, 255)); // Dark gray.
        window.draw(mushroom); // Drawing our sprite.
        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu baixei o Visual Studio 2015 e tentei rodar o código nele(todos os tutoriais de sfml são feitos com o vs 2015), e rodou perfeitamente.

Então o que estava acontecendo era que não tinha compatibilidade daquela versão do sfml com o vs 2017, o que deixa duas opções de solução pro meu problema:

-Usar o Visual Studio 2015 para programar, ou

-Recompilar as bibliotecas do sfml no Visual Studio 2017 (coisa que eu não sei como faz)